# How do you refer to something you will go back in time and do?

Tags: tenses, time

This is quite confusing for me, do you refer to it in future tense, past tense or would there need to be a new tense?

Comment: You'll have to consult Streetmentioner for this one.

Comment: It's tempting to express it as "I'll have done this earlier later."

Comment: Since there are no time machines, there is no need for a tense (current or invented) to deal with them. (The reason time travel confuses writers is that you are trying to discuss logical impossibilities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "going back in time" is a bit of a red herring here, a distraction. From the perspective of the actor/time-traveller, it is something he will do *next*, it isn't something he has already done, since he has not yet gone back in time.

In other words, from the subjective perspective of the actor, the events happening in the (new) past he travels to are actually in his future, and therefore the future tense is used.